# Drop Custom Shapes Visio 2016

Tags: vba, shapes, visio

I am attempting to drop a custom shape into my open Visio document, and link it to data which I have imported from a SQL database. I have the stencil loaded into Visio. Currently I can drop rectangles on the screen and link them. Here is what I have so far:

```
For i = 1 To 6

    Dim vsoDataRecordset As Visio.DataRecordset
    Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape
    Dim intCount As Integer

    intCount = Visio.ActiveDocument.DataRecordsets.Count
    Set vsoDataRecordset = Visio.ActiveDocument.DataRecordsets(intCount)

    Set vsoShape = ActivePage.DrawRectangle(1, 3, 2, 1)

    vsoShape.LinkToData vsoDataRecordset.ID, i, True
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that article by David J Parker [Creating a Schema from Visio External Data record sets](https://blog.bvisual.net/2014/03/26/creating-a-schema-from-visio-external-data-record-sets/) can help